# php_warning on installing ext

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I want to intstall the ext "my_redirects". On my local machine it does what it should. But now, on the live site, i got this error:

## 1: PHP Warning: file_get_contents(/kunden/homepages/28/d574274134/htdocs/update7/typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Private/Sql/Cache/Backend/Typo3DatabaseBackendCache.sql): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/28/d574274134/htdocs/update7/typo3_src-7.6.14/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/Backend/Typo3DatabaseBackend.php line 441

I got a hint to delete the typo3temp/autoload/ files. Then the installation works, but if i after that go into the install tool, i get this error again. Can someone give a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file is part of the core and must exist. Look into the src-tar/zip file. Maybe the file wasn't transferred to the server.

Comment: Ok, but why this file isnt there?How can this be? All my code is in an git repo and i do git pull on server.

Comment: Have you checked in the file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's an autoload issue, because the .sql file is missing, not the PHP class.

Please verify that the sql file does exist. If it's missing, check the hash of your downloaded TYPO3 core. Make sure you compare the correct path on the server.

But I guess you got an access restriction. Maybe bad ownhership of that .sql file? Perhaps you ran into some security problems with file_get_contents() and at least sql files? So please also check your security settings.